# Memory Efficient: Templates vs Basic data types

Tags: c++, templates, types

Is the use of templates better than basic data types in terms of memory allocation and management?

Comment: Is this a C++ question?

Comment: it would be great if it can be related with c++ or swift. @doctorlove

Comment: templates dont allocate memory, only if you instantiate it, but then it is not clear how this is different from "basic types"

Comment: C++ templates and Swift generics are completely different beasts.

Comment: Which are better: bricks or blueprints?

Comment: For C++ my guess would be: No, it makes no difference.

Comment: At least share one situation where you feel that you can replace one with the other.

Comment: @BoPersson thanks! 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in short:

templates - a way to write code once in a generic way, and in **compilation time** the compiler will generate code according to the template, if you used the templatic code.

example:

```
  #include <iostream>


template<typename T>
T MultiplyByFive(T _val)
{
    return _val * 5;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << MultiplyByFive(5) << " " << MultiplyByFive(5.5) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, the compiler will generate two MultiplyByFive functions. One for integer and one for double. The output will therefore be:

```
25 27.5
```

That's because these functions have been called. Now we have two function in the code (generated by the compiler)

```
int MultiplyByFive(int _val)
{
    return _val * 5;
}


double MultiplyByFive(double _val)
{
    return _val * 5;
}
```

We didn't code them directly, but the compiler did according to our **template**.

Memory allocation has little to do with template. Dynamic memory allocation is determined in **run time** (in c++ by the new operator). Static and local variable are determined in compile time, but it has nothing to do with **generating code**.

If I didn't understand the question, you're more then welcome to clarify.

Comment: Wow! I was curious, That if we apply templates/generics to our functions rather than any specific data type. Which one is recommended in terms of memory allocation and management.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
Allocation is about DATA. Templates are about CODE, functions etc.
You can use templates to do manipulation on data but it's usually just to show that you can.

What are you thinking about? give an example

Comment: you actually cleared my doubt. :D Thanks buddy. I wish I could have given an up vote to your reply.

Comment: If you like the answer, you can choose "accept the answer" by checking the gray check mark near my answer and making it green.

Comment: Done! Once again thanks for your efforts. ☺️ Much appreciated.